# Flooded Vault - lamp stuck in the raft; can't get out

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I got to the Flooded Vault tomb in Shipwreck Beach, and solved the puzzle. I went out of the tomb and went back in. When I got back in, the lamp was stuck in the raft:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried everything to get it out but nothing seems to work. The reason I went out was because I didn't know where to go. Do I have to go though the tomb or isn't it the right way?

Comment: Yeah...that's...not supposed to happen. You'll need to quit and reload as you need the boat under the lamp to stop the electified water.

Comment: since the boat has the rope around it that you can latch onto, why don't you try pulling it back towards you?

Comment: i ahve tried to reload the game, no cahgne there.

Comment: cant pull it...

Comment: Instead of just reloading, you might try reloading and traveling to a few other zones. In my game I had a graphical glitch in one of the final zones, and a reload didn't fix it. I traveled and walked around a few of the early zones and then when I went back to the end everything was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

try disabling your vsync.
 I can't explain it, but It somehow makes a difference.

I had a similar experience with tomb-raider anniversary. I can't remember details, but I know when I disabled the game vsync, I could get past the obstacle.

Hope this helps.